# Nilpotent matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra

If $N$ is an $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix such that $N^k=0$ for some integer $k$. Is it true that $(DN)^k=0$ for any diagonal matrix $D$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false.  A matrix is nilpotent iff all its eigenvalues are zero.  However, $DN$ need not have all eigenvalues zero.

For example, look at:
$$N=\begin{bmatrix} 
6 & -9 \\
4 & -6
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$D=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$N$ is nilpotent, but their product has eigenvalues 0 and -6 and thus isn't nilpotent.

Answer (score 6):

No. An important source of leverage in a situation like this is that nilpotence is a coordinate-independent condition (that is, it's invariant under change of basis) but being diagonal isn't. So up to change of basis you can replace "diagonal" with [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), and then it's easy to write down a counterexample, since e.g. any matrix with distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable over an algebraically closed field. Thus if $D = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\\ c & d \end{array} \right]$ is our mystery diagonalizable matrix, we can take $N = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ and compute that
$$DN = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & a \\\ 0 & c \end{array} \right]$$

which fails to be nilpotent if $c \neq 0$. And it's easy to choose appropriate values of $a, b, d$ so that $D$ has distinct eigenvalues.